# train Keras model with BatchNorm layer with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

I'm use **keras** to build a model, and write optimizing codes and all the others in **tensorflow**. When I was using quite simple layers like **Dense** or **Conv2D**, everything was straightforward. But adding **BatchNormalization** layer into my keras model makes problem complicated.

Since **BatchNormalization** layer behaves differently in training phase and testing phase, I figured out that I need **K.learning_phase():True** in my *feed_dict*. But following code is not working well. It runs with no error, but the model's performance isn't getting any better.

```
import keras.backend as K
...
x_train, y_train = get_data()
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train, K.learning_phase():True})
```

When I tried training keras model with keras **fit** function, it worked well.

What should I do to train a **keras** model with **BatchNormalization** layer in **tensorflow**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I duplicated this question that I hadn't seen.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654483/model-with-batchnormalization-stagnant-test-loss), it just consists in passing an special argument to the BatchNormalization layer call

Comment: i was wrong, it does not work in the end... i don't know why