# Model with BatchNormalization: stagnant test loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I wrote a neural network using Keras. It contains BatchNormalization layers.

When I trained it with `model.fit`, everything was fine. When training it with tensorflow [as explained here](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#calling-keras-layers-on-tensorflow-tensors), the training is fine, but the validation step always give very poor performance, and it quickly saturates (the accuracy goes 5%, 10%, 40%, 40%, 40%..; the loss is stagnant too).

I need to use tensorflow because it allows more flexibility regarding the monitoring part of training.

I strongly suspect it has something to do with BN layers or/and the way I compute the test performances (see below)

```
feed_dict = {x: X_valid,
            batch_size_placeholder: X_valid.shape[0],
            K.learning_phase(): 0,
            beta: self.warm_up_schedule(global_step)
            }
if self.weights is not None:
    feed_dict[weights] = self.weights
acc = accuracy.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Is there anything special to do when computing the validation accuracy of a model containing Keras BatchNormalizatin layers ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out about the `training` argument of the [`__call__` method of the `BatchNormalization` layer](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L126)

So what you can do when instantiating the layer is just:

```
x = Input((dim1, dim2))
h = Dense(dim3)(x)
h = BatchNormalization()(h, training=K.learning_phase())
```

And when evaluating the performance on validation set:

```
feed_dict = {x: X_valid,
             batch_size_placeholder: X_valid.shape[0],
             K.learning_phase(): 0,
             beta: self.warm_up_schedule(global_step)
             }
acc = accuracy.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
summary_ = merged.eval(feed_dict=feed_dict)
test_writer.add_summary(summary_, global_step)
```

Comment: well actually I was wrong, it does not work but i don't get why

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem and found that setting `training=1` in `BatchNormalization`'s `__call__` seems to work. Setting `K.learning_phase()` to either 0 or 1 doesn't seem to have an affect on the output as far as batch normalization is concerned, and as long as you're not running your training op the batch norm parameters shouldn't change.

Comment: so you would recommend to use a different placeholder instead of K.learning_phase() ?